# Get business days between consecutive rows pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Pretty straightforward question.

I know:

```
df.diff()
```

gives me the days between, and I know I could do some kind of mojo with

```
df.loc[df.Date.weekday == 4, 'Diff'] = 1
```

But that isn't optimal. I tried

```
np.busday_count()
```

But am getting an error I don't quite understand. Here's example code with that error:

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1: {'Date': '2016-01-01'}, 2: {'Date': '2016-01-02'}, 3: {'Date': '2016-01-03'}}, orient='index')

In [37]: df['Date'] = df.Date.astype('<M8[D]')

In [38]: np.busday_count(df.Date, df.Date.shift(1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-07a4ae9a16f6> in <module>()
----> 1 np.busday_count(df.Date, df.Date.shift(1))

TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'

In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({1: {'Date': '2016-01-01'}, 2: {'Date': '2016-01-02'}, 3: {'Date': '2016-01-03'}}, orient='index')

In [40]: np.busday_count(df.Date, df.Date.shift(1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-07a4ae9a16f6> in <module>()
----> 1 np.busday_count(df.Date, df.Date.shift(1))

TypeError: Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references, but the REFS_OK flag was not enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

So I don't know if this fits *everyones* needs, but this works:

```
np.busday_count(df.Date.values.tolist(), df.Date.shift(1).fillna(df.Date).values.tolist())
```

So adding in the tolist(), and the .fillna() parts were both necessary!

Comment: A clean solution with explicit typecast to NumPy dtype `datetime64[D]` works without conversion to list: `np.busday_count(df.Date.values.astype('datetime64[D]'), df.Date.shift(1).fillna(df.Date).values.astype('datetime64[D‌​]'))`. Therefore this should be faster, but it not so readable. I would probably write a function "my_busday_count" with all these conversions that works consistently on pd.Series / np.vectors and outputs correctly NaT where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

With `np.busday_count` you may try as well:

```
x3 = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in df.Date]
x4 = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in df.Date.shift(1).fillna(0)]
np.busday_count(x4,x3)
array([12001,     1,     0])

%timeit np.busday_count(x4,x3)
The slowest run took 4.58 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop
```

or if you wish:

```
x1 = [x.date() for x in df.Date]
x2 = [x.date() for x in df.Date.shift(1).fillna(0)]
np.busday_count(x2,x1)
array([12001,     1,     0])

%timeit np.busday_count(x2,x1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.4 µs per loop
```